# Custom annotationView images revert to pins when clicked

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

I'm displaying custom images on a map (instead of the default pins) using the code below. However, when I tap on an item (and the callout appears), the image reverts to the default red pin. How can I keep my custom image, even when the callout is displayed?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;

    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *pinID = @"mapPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:pinID];
        if (pinAnnotation == nil)
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinID] autorelease];

        // Set the image
        pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestIcon.png"];

        // Set ability to show callout
        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        // Set up the disclosure button on the right side
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

        [pinID release];
    }

    return pinAnnotation;
    [pinAnnotation release];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found by making the pinAnnotation a MKAnnotationView rather than a MKPinAnnotationView, I got the desired result. Image doesn't turn into a pin anymore

```
    static NSString *pinID = @"mapPin";
    pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:pinID];
    if (pinAnnotation == nil)
        pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinID] autorelease];

    // Set the image
    pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestIcon.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subview rather than the image property. This code succssfully solves the problem for me:

```
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pin.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
    [annView addSubview:imageView];
```