# MKAnnotationView and ImageView

Tags: iphone, imageview, mkannotationview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call pin annotation on button click in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058939/how-to-call-pin-annotation-on-button-click-in-iphone)

Sorry if question is strange. I'm trying to have an image and drop pins on certain parts and name those parts. Anytime I search Image+Iphone+Drp Pins I get MKAnnotationView or at least something that begins with MK. Now I wonder, is MKAnnotationView only for maps or I can use it to display images and drop pins on them as well. If I can, how do I do that. I mean with imageview it's very simple. I can do it with both code and IB. What about MKAnnotationView. Can it be a subview to another view?

Comment: how big is the image, and how many pins are you planning on dropping?

Comment: The image is going to take the entire screen except for the navigation bar. And it's going to be varios parts of the human body.Let's say the temporal bone, which contains 80 different regions on it. What I'd really like to do is, make some pins always visible but some, which are very tiny, only when zoomed in to a certain scale.

Comment: sorry, I meant the resolution. if the image is only 960 x 640, then a normal UIView will do, but if you are going to have an image that can be zoomed in on, then you will want a CATiledLayer for the image. as for the pins, MKAnnotationView is used for maps, with coordinates, so you will probably want to animate them in as UIImageViews or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to achieve but Please figure out this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058939/how-to-call-pin-annotation-on-button-click-in-iphone) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576211/custom-annotationview-images-revert-to-pins-when-clicked) , [Link3](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/)

Hope It will help you to achieve your target.

Happy Coding.